PHP cropped image to base64 string
i've been trying to crop some images using PHP and convert those images to a base 64 string ... I've found a way that works but it is filling my transparent background with black!
Does anyone know a better way to accomplish this? Or maybe some way to prevent the transparent background of my pngs from being filled in during the process. Thanks in advance!
$image = imagecreatefrompng('/path to my image');
$cropped_image = imagecrop($image, [
    'x' => $temp->asset->offset->x,
    'y' => $temp->asset->offset->y,
    'width' => $temp->asset->width,
    'height' => $temp->asset->height
]);
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
imagepng($cropped_image, $stream);
rewind($stream);
$temp->asset->src = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(stream_get_contents($stream));
imagedestroy($image);


To set whether a GdImage should preserve the alpha channel information (transparency) on save, you can use imagesavealpha. In your case, you can add the following before the call to imagepng:
imagesavealpha($cropped_image, true);

changing your example to:
$image = imagecreatefrompng('/path to my image');
$cropped_image = imagecrop($image, [
    'x' => $temp->asset->offset->x,
    'y' => $temp->asset->offset->y,
    'width' => $temp->asset->width,
    'height' => $temp->asset->height
]);
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
imagesavealpha($cropped_image, true);
imagepng($cropped_image, $stream);
rewind($stream);
$temp->asset->src = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(stream_get_contents($stream));
imagedestroy($image);


Just tested and it works perfectly!! Thanks so much! The PHP docs should really associate these functions better xD

@SpencerMay agreed. For what it's worth, I discovered that by looking at the list here (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) and scanning for anything that mentions alpha.
